# NiFi key value pair text to json/avro

Tags: apache-nifi

I have the following key value pair data. How do I convert them to json or avro format?

```
col_name1=a col_name2=b col_name3=c
```

Comment: Where do you have this data? Is it read from file? Provide more details about the nature of your flow, you will get more responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat this as CSV text (using a space `' '` as the delimiter) and use the `ConvertRecord` processor to convert from CSV to JSON or Avro.